# In Android Studio how to create jar Including other jar libraries

Tags: android, jar, android-library

In android studio, i'm trying to create .jar file of my library and it contains another .jar dependancies. After adding created .jar file to another project and run it gives me

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{in.co.xyz.MyLibrary/in.co.xyz.MyLibrary.MainActivity}:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "in.co.xyz.MyLibrary.MainActivity" 
on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/in.co.xyz.MyLibrary-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

how to fix this issue, please help me

Answer (score 1):

you cannot do this, if its must you have to include all java inside your project so that it will compile with same build.

Because .jar is container of compiled files.

Comment: yes it will compile but wont be able to access other classes which is inside other jar files

Comment: dear solution is, you have to add .java files in place of jar file.

Comment: can we create fatjar file??

Comment: NO you cannot .